# Get entries with consecutive week

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table with two ID columns and one date column. I am trying to get the number of consecutive weeks based on the date column

```
|ID|ID2|Date      |
|1 | 1 |2018-01-01|
|1 | 1 |2018-01-08|
|1 | 1 |2018-01-15|
|2 | 1 |2018-01-01|
|2 | 1 |2018-01-08|
|2 | 2 |2018-01-01|
```

What i am trying to achieve is a table like this

```
|ID |ID2|Consecutive Week|
|1  | 1 |3               |
|2  | 1 |2               |
|2  | 2 |1               |
```

I'm stuck with the following code:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.ID2 ,consec_set, COUNT(1) AS consec_count
FROM
(
   SELECT IF(b.Date IS NULL, @val:=@val+1, @val) AS consec_set,a.ID2
   FROM tbl a
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @val:=0) var_init
   LEFT JOIN tbl b ON 
       a.ID = b.ID AND
       a.ID2 = b.ID2 AND
       YEARWEEK(a.Date ,1) = YEARWEEK(b.Date ,1) + 1
   WHERE a.ID= 1
) a
GROUP BY a.consec_set;
```

I reached this code following several guides here but they were only with consecutive days and one ID only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define 'week'.

Comment: @Strawberry by 'week' i mean week of the year or the result from YEARWEEK(Date,1) for example. Consecutive week would be ( for example ) an ID with at least one entry on week number 1 and week number 2 of the year.

Comment: I'm not clear what your output would look like if 1,1 also had date 2018-02-10 (for example) ie what if there are multiple discrete consecutive yearweeks.

Comment: For ID=2 and ID2=1 the week is not consecutive. Both dates are in the same week. Should it be 1?

Comment: @TahaPaksu Yes, the Date should be 2018-01-08. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @P.Salmon In your example the consecutive week value would still be 3.

Comment: What if there's this line on the table, `|1 | 1 |2018-02-15|`, what should be the output?

Comment: @TahaPaksu Good point. I need the longest consecutive streak but i only need help with finding the consecutive weeks and not make you do my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I succeeded the SQL. A bit complicated though.

```
SELECT id, id2, Max(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT id, id2, Count(id) AS CNT FROM (
        SELECT *, (
            SELECT @num:=Ifnull(@num,0)) AS grouper, 
                   @num := IF(cntn=0, @num+1, @num) AS row_number  
            FROM (
                SELECT a.id, a.id2, a.wno, b.id IS NOT NULL AS CNTN 
                FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT id, id2, Week(pdate) AS WNO FROM listing) a
                    LEFT JOIN
                        (SELECT DISTINCT id, id2, Week(pdate) AS WNO FROM listing) b
                    ON a.wno = b.wno - 1 AND a.id = b.id AND a.id2 = b.id2
                    ORDER BY a.id, a.id2, a.wno
                ) d 
            ) e GROUP BY e.id, e.id2, e.grouper
        ) f GROUP BY f.id, f.id2
```

Heres the fiddle with all the cases I said in the comments included:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b785df/71

Explaining from the inside out:

1. Selected the distinct WeekNumber, ID, ID2 values from the table
2. Joined the 1. table to itself again on the consecutive ones if it exists
3. Converted the joined rows into booleans whether the consecutive record exists or not.
4. Grouped the consecutive rows with indexes like 1,2,3 etc
5. Selected the count of the groups
6. Selected the maximum of the groups of which have the same ID and ID1's.

Comment: Freaking legend man ! 6 hours of struggling. You are a life savior !

Comment: Thanks, I like challenging ones :)

Comment: 0.0220 seconds per 300 000 entries

Comment: Nice :) I didn't expect that speed.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment.

Consider the following:

```
SELECT *, YEARWEEK(date,1) yw FROM my_table;
+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| ID1 | ID2 | Date       | yw     |
+-----+-----+------------+--------+
|   1 |   1 | 2018-01-01 | 201801 |
|   1 |   1 | 2018-01-08 | 201802 |
|   1 |   1 | 2018-01-15 | 201803 |
|   2 |   1 | 2018-01-01 | 201801 |
|   2 |   1 | 2018-01-07 | 201801 |
|   2 |   2 | 2018-01-01 | 201801 |
+-----+-----+------------+--------+

1,1 = 3 consecutive weeks
2,1 = 1 week
2,2 = 1 week
```

Comment: Good thinking but i think this method would slow down the execution time because i need to make an extra select on a table with over 300 000 entries. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There's no 'thinking'  going on here. I'm merely demonstrating that there are 3 consecutive weeks, 1 consecutive, and a further 1 consecutive week.